# Get Extras in Single Instance Mode

Tags: android

I want to put some extras with putextras(,) in notification , 
but my activity is in **Single Instance** Mode and in OnResume I can not get any extras .
how can I solve this problem ?

```
intent.putExtra("keyboard", false);

//

if (getIntent().hasExtra("keyboard")) {

            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("keyboard", true) == false) {
                _HideKeyaboard();

            }
        }
```

I receive null on get extras .

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I don't see the connection between Single Instance mode and Intent extras

Comment: Indeed, what evidence (doc citation, error message, etc) do you have to suggest that Intent Extras are incompatible with Single Instance?  Have you verified that your code works in a non single instance mode?

Comment: I receive null on get extras .

Comment: you don't need the first if `if (getIntent().hasExtra("keyboard"))` in this case. You provide `true` in case the extra is not found which will skip the if-case anyway.

Comment: @yoshi , sorry , but I do not understand what you want tell me .

Comment: I'm wondering why you check `if (getIntent().hasExtra("keyboard"))`.

Comment: Because `.getBooleanExtra("keyboard", true)` will return `true`  if  `keyboard` is not found. That's result in `if (true == false) ...` => skip. dev.android (^.^)-> http://bit.ly/JN9W7K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onsaveinstancestate you can save your data. 
onrestoreinstancestate you can retrieve. these always call when activity goes on pause or resume.

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      savedInstanceState.putExtra("keyboard", false);
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

   @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outbundle) {
      outbundle.getBooleanExtra("keyboard", true);
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outbundle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the [onNewintent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method for Activity