# Android - pass data to singleInstance activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I have an activity that is defined in the manifest as:

```
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Now I want to move to that activity from a different activity that has no idea that it exists (no reference to the existing instance) and at the same time to pass in a variable. I used to do this like so (before I defined it as singleInstance):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, receivingactivity.class);

intent.putExtra("somekey", somevalue);

startActivity(intent);
```

But now that doesn't work anymore. I put in the receiving activity the following lines in onresume:

```
String somevalue = getIntent().getStringExtra("somekey");
```

and it returns null. How can I pass a value to the existing receiving activity (which is always active and never gets to ondestroy but maximum to onpause)?

Comment: `onDestroy()` can always happen if the system needs memory. Anyway, I'm not if that could help, but here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356277/get-extras-in-single-instance-mode

Comment: @shkschneider thanks - that's true. Whatever the case, it should always pass through onresume when the receivingactivity restarts, and that's where I want to extract the input argument. I just can't get the input argument into the activity

Comment: you can use shared preference:   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Hi @Jon Did you got resolved this issue ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` to retrieve intent passed to it if the activity's launch mode is singleInstance and provided it's not destroyed.

Do not be confused with `getIntent()` for this one retrieves intent passed on the activity's creation.

Comment: Isn't `onNewIntent()` only for `singleTop` flag?

Comment: Hi @inmyth am facing the same problem.. am not getting data in onNewIntent() also.. Any other suggestions?